# Stackoverflow error when uses Apache Jmeter Core

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, kotlin, jmeter, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am new in Gradle. I am using my gradle with kotlin dsl script. When I execute using

> gradle bootRun

Then it throw StackoverFlow error for log4J

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError   at
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.(InvocationTargetException.java:72)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocator.getCallerClass(StackLocator.java:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocator.getCallerClass(StackLocator.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocatorUtil.getCallerClass(StackLocatorUtil.java:55)

As Soon as I comment the **implementation( "org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_core:5.0")** from the build script, it doesn't throw any Error, what I should do? Please help.

## Build.Gradle.kts

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile


plugins {
    java
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.11"
    "kotlin-spring"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.1.1.RELEASE"
}

group = "org.kayd"
version = "1.0-DEV"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    implementation(kotlin("reflect"))
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.2")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.1.1.RELEASE")
    implementation( "org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_core:5.0")
//    implementation("org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_java:5.0")
//    implementation( "org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_http:5.0")
//    implementation( "org.antlr:antlr:3.1.3")
//    implementation( "org.json:json:20180813")
    testCompile("junit", "junit", "4.12")
}

configure<JavaPluginConvention> {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

## Main Fun file

```
package org.kayd

import org.springframework.boot.Banner
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication

@EnableConfigurationProperties
@SpringBootApplication
open class StartApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<StartApplication>(*args) {
        setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF)
        setLogStartupInfo(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you [list your project dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:listing_dependencies) you will see that

- [`org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_core:5.0`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_core/5.0) has transitive dependency on [`commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2)
- which in its turn clashes with your [`org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.2`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.2)

So you're suffering from a form of a [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell). You cannot reliably use 2 different versions of a same JAR in one application as the order of loaded classes in the [CLASSPATH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) is a big question mark. Theoretically you can control this using a [custom classloader](http://blog.markturansky.com/archives/21) however it might be an overkill for your project.

The easiest would be just removing your `implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.2")` dependency and re-write the impacted code to use [Commons Collections 3 syntax](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.2/index.html).

Alternatively you will have to reconsider the way you're using JMeter in your application and go for [one of the alternative JMeter execution options](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui).